# Build failed in TFS

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild

I am using TFS for Automation build, I installed TFS-2013, .net framework 4.5.1 on the server. I created an application and build definition in TFS.

When I am triggering build from my system, it is showing this error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (97): Invalid static method invocation syntax:
>   "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPlatformSDKDisplayName($(TargetPlatformIdentifier),
>   $(TargetPlatformVersion))". Method
>   'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.GetPlatformSDKDisplayName'
>   not found. Static method invocation should be of the form:
>   $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`,
>   `b`)).

Answer (score 0):

Your build server should mirror your developer workstation.

You should have Visual Studio (which will bring the SDK) and everything else that your developers need to build locally.

Comment: Is Visual studio required on TFS server?

Comment: Not unless it is also The build server (not recommended)

Comment: I have VS2013 installed on my build server and am also getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help, the issue got resolved for me by applying Visual Studio Update 5.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/F/9/AF95E6F8-2E6E-49D0-A48A-8E918D7FD768/vs2013.5.iso